# Overscan resets

Tags: pi-2

I have a problem with my raspberry pi, the screen I'm working on with 1920x1200.
The issue is that when I enable overscan using set_overscan from https://github.com/ukscone/set_overscan, it goes well at the start, but when I restart the whole thing resets itself.

Also sometimes it does save and sync but when I reboot the issue returns, how can I sync/save it so it remains?

I use a raspberry pi 2b and my os is Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

found it, i was editing the wrong file,

normally in a raspberry pi the config file is `/boot/config.txt`
but with ubuntu this is a dummy file, you need to change `/boot/firmware/config.txt`